# imageitem class define

Tags: objective-c, class, set, declaration

i need to build an application that define an array that should be made of image items.
every image iten has an image, a name and a photographer name.
i build my image item class and i want you to check if my define is correct and good(i just start to learn objective c).
i want you to emphasize on the set's methods.

here is the photoitem.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface photoItem : NSObject
 {
     UIImage *imageView;
     NSString *photoNameLabel;
     NSString *photographerNameLabel;
     UIButton *viewPhoto;
 }
 @property(readonly) NSString *name;
 @property(readonly) NSString *nameOfPhotographer;
 @property(readonly) UIImage *imageItem;

 -(id)makePhotoItemWIthPhoto:(UIImage*)image name:(NSString*)photoName photographer:   (NSString*)photographerName;

@end
```

here is my photoitem.m:

```
#import "photoItem.h"

@implementation photoItem

@synthesize name;
@synthesize nameOfPhotographer;
@synthesize imageItem;

-(id)makePhotoItemWIthPhoto:(UIImage*)image name:(NSString*)photoName photographer:(NSString*)photographerName
{
    [self setName:photoName];
    [self setNameOfPhotographer:photographerName];
    [self setImageItem:image];
    return self;
}

-(void) setName:(NSString *)name
{
    photoNameLabel = name;
}  

-(void) setNameOfPhotographer:(NSString *)nameOfPhotographer
{
    photographerNameLabel = nameOfPhotographer;
}

-(void)setImageItem:(UIImage *)imageItem
{
    imageView = imageItem;
}
@end
```

i hope you could fix my errors(if there are some).
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems come to mind:

1) `-(id)makePhotoItemWIthPhoto:name:photographer:` might be better as `-(id)initWithPhoto:name:photographer:`.  Otherwise the caller needs to `alloc` and `init` an object first so that `self` is valid, then call your method.  At that point, the return of `self` doesn't make sense.
Example:

```
-(idinitWithPhoto:(UIImage*)image name:(NSString*)photoName photographer:(NSString*)photographerName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setName:photoName];
        [self setNameOfPhotographer:photographerName];
        [self setImageItem:image];
    }
    return self;
}
```

2) The three readonly properties don't seem to have any purpose since they have no connection to the variables that you initialize in the `makePhotoItemWIthPhoto:` method.